# How do I make this command not break the entire bot if it isn't a valid api url

Tags: javascript, api, axios, discord.js

If I type a valid API key it works, if I don't it doesn't just not work it breaks the entire bot.

```
const text = options.getString('url')
            axios.get(text).then(resp => { //TODO: make it so the bot doesn't have to be rehosted if the API isn't valid
                const contenttotext = JSON.stringify(resp.data)
                interaction.reply({
                content: contenttotext
             })
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
axios.get(text)
  .then((res) => {
    /*handle response*/
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     /* handle error */
  })
```

You should really look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and [Axios' Example Section](https://www.npmjs.com/package//axios#example) which shows this.